# Stack Snippets を使えるようにしてほしい

Tags: 機能の要求, 完了

2014年9月に、HTML + CSS + JavaScript を投稿内に埋め込んで jsFiddle のように実行できる機能「[Stack Snippets](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)」が英語版SOに導入されました。日本語版でも使えるようにしてほしいです。

[ポルトガル語版](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2006/habilitar-os-stack-snippets-aqui)でも、はじめは有効になっていなかったものの、現在は使えるようになっているようです。

[image: stack snippets button]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

使えるようになりましたが、英語になっています。中のストリング全体を翻訳しますが、しばらく時間がかかります。とりあえず、英語で理解できる範囲に使ってください。

Comment: [メタでも有効に](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/1616/30)できますか? [meta.se](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)や[meta.so](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)では有効になっています。

Comment: @ento メタSEは特別ですが、通常（meta.SOを含む）メタに有効していないです。

Comment: meta.soでは有効になっていました。[meta.pt.so](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)では有効ではないですね。ユースケースとしては、メタでSnippetsを試せる[サンドボックス](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269754/20226)を作る、各種フレームワークをロードする方法をまとめたFAQを作る、を考えています。

Comment: @ento 適用済みです。テストしてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます!