# 検索機能の改善：kuromojiを導入しました

Tags: 機能の要求, 完了, 検索

Stack Overflowは英語で開発したため、検索が英語を想定していました。日本語と英語での検索の一番大きな違いは言葉の間にスペースが存在しているかどうかです。

英語の検索はスペースを想定しているため、日本語での検索結果がよくなかったため、日本語での検索機能を「[kuromoji](http://www.atilika.org/)」に更新しました。

検索についてバグや疑問があれば、ご教示ください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this. English words will be stemmed now so that "snippet" and "snippets" both work.

---

[「snippet」で検索しても「snippets」がヒットしない問題を] 修正しました。英単語であれば語幹でマッチさせるようにしたので、「snippet」でも「snippets」でも検索できるようになっています。

Comment: Are they stemmed only when all the search keywords are in English? I noticed that "Snippets" isn't highlighted in [the search result for "snippet 使える"](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=snippet+%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B).

Comment: Highlighting isn't 100% reliable but they are stemmed regardless and the results appear accurately.

Comment: Ah right, "snippet 使える" should have had zero results if "snippet" weren't stemmed, because the keywords are ANDed. (まとめ: 日本語と英語のキーワードを混ぜてもちゃんと語幹処理がされる。ただし今のところ確実にはハイライトされない)

Answer (score 2):

「ヘルプ」→「ヘルプセンター」→「ヘルプページを検索する」で日本語で検索すると、検索キーワードが日本語の文字単位に分割されてしまい、適切な検索結果が得られません。

[image: 検索結果]

Comment: 補足情報: 文字単位で分割されてしまう場合と、そうでない場合があるようです。「おすすめ」だと文字単位になりますが、「[ロールバック](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%83%90%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF)」だと単語単位で検索できました。

Comment: 開発者に連絡していますが、別のインデックスがあるため、調整が必要です。

Comment: これも解決済みです。ヘルプでのサーチも黒文字を利用して問題なく実行できます。

Answer (score 1):

["snippet"](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=snippet) で ["snippets"](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/221/30) がヒットしません。

[英語版ではヒットしている](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=snippet)ように見えます。少なくとも **snippets** という単語が検索結果でハイライトされています。

Comment: 開発者に聞いています。後日結果を連絡させていただきます。

Comment: 下のHaneyの回答の通り、英語での検索なら出てくるようにしました